# how to put await in then portion under Promise.all

Tags: javascript, promise

In the following code, I used `Promise.all` to enable async called when calling map, but in the `then` portion, i need another call to `await`, the syntax does not allow me to do that, what's the way to enable `await` under `then` branch? Alternatively, is there more elegant way to achieve the same purpose of my code without introducing so many different constructs like `Promise.all`?

```
 const handleSend = async ({ text, attachments }) => {
        const attachmentsArr = null;

        Promise.all(attachments.map(async a => {//<--use Promise all for async within map
            const isImage = a.type.startsWith('image/');
            let response = null;
            if (isImage) { response = await channel.sendImage(a); } else { response = await channel.sendFile(a); }
            return {
                name: a.name,
                path: response.file,
                size: a.size,
                isImage
            };
        })).then(attachmentsArr => {
            await channel.sendMessage({ //<--can't use await here
                text,
                workspaceId: '1234567',
                attachments: attachmentsArr
            });

        }

        );
    };
```

Comment: You have many options. (1) `var attachmentsArr = await Promise.all(attachments.map(async a => {...})); await channel.SendMessage(...);` (2) `.then(async attachmentsArray => { ... })`.

Answer (score 0):

I would write it like this

```
const handleSend = async ({ text, attachments }) => {

  const promisesArray = attachments.map(async a => {
    const isImage = a.type.startsWith('image/');
    let response = null;
    if (isImage) {
      response = await channel.sendImage(a);
    } else {
      response = await channel.sendFile(a);
    }
    return {
      name: a.name,
      path: response.file,
      size: a.size,
      isImage
    };
  });

  const attachmentsArr = await Promise.all(promisesArray);

  await channel.sendMessage({
    text,
    workspaceId: '1234567',
    attachments: attachmentsArr
  });

};
```

But, you should check attachmentsArr and see how to know when is empty to send null.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing `async/await` with `then` can be confusing. You can instead write it all in async/await syntax like Braian's answer, or in `then` syntax like this:

```js
const handleSend = ({ text, attachments }) => {
  Promise.all(attachments.map(async a => {
    const isImage = a.type.startsWith('image/');
    let response = null;
    if (isImage) { response = await channel.sendImage(a); } else { response = await channel.sendFile(a); }
    return {
      name: a.name,
      path: response.file,
      size: a.size,
      isImage
    };
  })).then(attachmentsArr => {
    return channel.sendMessage({ // <--- Return a promise
      text,
      workspaceId: '1234567',
      attachments: attachmentsArr
    });
  }).then((result) => { // <--- Operate on the resolved value
    // Do something with result
  });
};
```

Comment: "*Mixing `async`/`await` with `then` can be confusing*" - then why are you still doing it?

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for pointing that out, that `async` keyword isn't necessary since I'm not awaiting anywhere. Edited.